# Links not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink

For whatever reason, the main menu links on http://www.ockelborum.se aren't clickable in Internet Explorer for some visitors. They work fine in all other browsers, on all platforms. The code for the links looks like this:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/index.html">Hem</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/lagenheter-lingbo.html">Lägenheter i Lingbo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/lagenheter-ockelbo.html">Lägenheter i Ockelbo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/overnattningsrum.html">Övernattningsrum</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/hotellkontakt.html" class="active">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/erbjudanden.html">Erbjudanden</a></li>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And you'll find the stylesheet here: http://www.ockelborum.se/style.css

I'm really hoping someone can give me a hand with this, because I'm stumped. Oh, and at least one of the visitors used IE8.

Comment: What's the problem, I've tried all IE what I have: IE 7,8,9 and it works....

Comment: Can't repro that, works like a charm with IE 7-9.

Comment: It works fine from here, but three different people have told me that they can't click the links.

Comment: btw in standard a should have also alt attribute.

Comment: @Jakub Oboza

Why would he need alt tags in anchor tags?

Comment: I still have no idea what caused it, but one of the visitors said it's working now. I'll update if I find out.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to Internet Explorer 6?  If not, and if you DO have Windows 7 installed, try to download Windows XP Mode, the virtual machine.  It comes with IE6 preinstalled...which is the IE I'm betting those people who claim they can't click the links are using.

My guess is you're floating your unordered list items and you've put the clear in the wrong spot (it should come after the closing unordered list  tag).  Somehow, that *MAY* be causing a problem since you're not supposed to have anything outside of list items inside an unordered/ordered list.

What I think you need to do is move the clear outside the unordered list like this:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/index.html">Hem</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/lagenheter-lingbo.html">Lägenheter i Lingbo</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/lagenheter-ockelbo.html">Lägenheter i Ockelbo</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/overnattningsrum.html">Övernattningsrum</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/hotellkontakt.html" class="active">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ockelborum.se/erbjudanden.html">Erbjudanden</a></li>        
  </ul>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try that out, but at least one of the visitors used IE8.